# Object not showing up in Layout, but visible in Modelling and Render

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, visibility

I was trying out Blender Guru's Donut tutorial and got stuck while making the cup. The plane and the donut are not visible in the Layout tab even though the visibility is set. Everything is working fine in the Modelling tab and in the rendered image, so I'm sure it's a silly error which made this happen.
I am not on Local view and I tried Alt + H, does not work. Blender version 2.92.0

Layout view
[image: Layout Tab view]

Modelling View
[image: Modelling Tab View]

Here is my Blender file:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3D Viewport has some own visiblity options if you bring up the sidebar with <kbd>N</kbd>, where you can disable visibility for certain collections. In the *Layout View* they are all disabled apart from the one that holds the camera and the light. The cup and saucer only show up there because they are not in one of those collections.

Disabling the *Local Collections* checkbox makes Blender ignore the *Viewport* settings for collections and shows them according to the settings in the *Outliner*. By default this setting is disabled so that the *Viewport* always uses the *Outliner* settings - I don't know why it's enabled in your scene.

[image: 3d viewport options]

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. I have no idea how I enabled it, I may have accidentally entered the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

I Had the same problem and solved it by simply closing the Layout window (Tab 'Layout' > right click > 'Delete') and reopen it (Tab '+' > right click > 'Layout' - you might eventually want to reorder it to the front again). Save the file and you're done.

Cheers!

*Note: The relevant collections were set to visible in both Layout and Modelling. The meshes were also not hidden and 'Local collections' was unchecked in both windows.*

Answer (score 0):

Both the donut and sprinkles are shown as disabled in the outliner. Click the checkboxes to enable them and see if that fixes your problem.[image]

Comment: I tried that and updated my screenshots, it did not work.

Comment: You'll need to upload the blend file in that case so that we can see what's going on. https://blend-exchange.com/ and read the instructions there.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded the Blend file now.

Comment: Ok. It's now appeared so I'll have a look.

Comment: I can't explain that one, but it has to be something to do with a setting in the UI. If you load Blender, choose File > Open and then uncheck Load UI via the gear wheel at the top right of the file dialog before clicking Open, it loads correctly and is visible both in layout and modelling view. However, if you just load the file normally it displays the problem you've seen! The only thing I can suggest is loading it that way then immediately saving it. That should save the settings correctly and sort the problem.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot John. I'll keep this question open in case someone gets a proper fix to this problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'd love to hear the reason too!

Comment: @JohnEason I've put my answer here to give you the reason ;)

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for that. I've never really had cause to investigate local collections before so didn't know that one! Yet another thing to file away in my addled 75 year-old brain! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason Never used it either, I just found it because of the question  :D

Answer (score 0):

Check if and how overlays are shown.
[image]